# Puppeteer JS headers for scraping

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to find out how to add headers to puppeteer js.  I'm building something for the first time so I'm not familiar with this.

If set up my file with these, based on documentation but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly:

```
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36');
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({Referer: 'https://example.com/'});
```

Other than that tutorials that I've searched aren't adding the headers.

I want to add headers to replicate a real user in my case I’d like to replicate my browser as if I was using it manually.  What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Well, according to the specs you are right. use `setExtraHTTPHeaders`. So what's the question here?

Comment: How do I replicate my headers to make it as if I’m manually browsing?  I added it also the the questions @Vaviloff

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, the english language is set by default when puppeteer visit the site.

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({'Cookie': 'language=en'});
```

In the browser you will find your data.

[cookie on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVkxI.png)